# AWS Redshift spectrum ERROR: syntax error at or near "json"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want to create an **external table using redshift spectrum**, files are `stored in s3 as json file having a single object with values as an array of objects`.

my query for the external table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE jatinspectrum.extable (
enteries array<struct<title:varchar(4000),link:varchar(4000),author:varchar(4000),published_date:timestamp,category:array<varchar(4000)>>>
)
stored as json
LOCATION 's3://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/';
```

it throws an error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "json" Position: 198`

just to make sure that i am syntactically right i saved it as text file using another query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE jatinspectrum.extab (
enteries array<struct<title:varchar(4000),link:varchar(4000),author:varchar(4000),published_date:timestamp,category:array<varchar(4000)>>>
)
stored as textfile
LOCATION 's3://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/';
```

*this worked perfectly but this won't help me since nested data is not supported for text query.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me, need to changes this `stored as textfile` to this

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
stored as textfile
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/parsing-JSON.html